# @Resource Injection in jar in 'lib' of an ear; why doesn't that work?

Tags: dependency-injection, glassfish, java-ee-6, cdi

I have simple ear  (GF 4.0, JDK 7; sticking with EE6 for now)

The ear contains:

EJBJar

WAR

lib/Shared.jar

Shared has an @Qualifier  (@UserDS) in it (it also has META-INF/beans.xml).

I have an @Producer like this:

```
package fhw.producers;
import fhw.qaulifiers.ListingDS;
import fhw.qaulifiers.UserDS;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

@Default
public class DataSourceProducer
{
    @Resource(lookup = "Member")
    private DataSource userDS;        

    public DataSourceProducer()
    {
        System.err.println("DataSourceProducer.DataSourceProducer -- CONSTRUCTION"); 
    }

    @Produces
    @UserDS
    public DataSource getUserDataSource()
    {
        System.err.println("******DataSourceProducer.getUserDataSource; am I null?  " + (null == userDS) ) ;
        return userDS;
    }
}
```

I have a simple EJB  (it has a beans.xml) that uses it via:

```
    @Inject
    @UserDS
    private DataSource userDS;
```

**QUESTION**:   When I put DataSourceProducer in the EJBJAR and deploy; my print statements come out and my @Resource resolves and everything is fine.    When I put DataSourceProducer in the Shared.jar; the print statements still come out but the @Resource didn't work and the EJB NPE's on the null DS returned by producer method etc.    In both tests the qualifier stayed in the Shared.jar.   I have no DDs anyway where (well a web.xml for the war -- all else is implicit)

Part of me thinks this makes a bit of sense; @Resource is sort of EE oriented (or no?); and should mostly make sense within a EE deployable.

OTOH, why can't have I have hand-full of qualifiers and some producers in a Shared JAR in lib dir of an EAR that all EJBJars and WARs (in the EAR) can use?

Is there a way to make this work?

If you really want -- you can see an entire example here:   https://github.com/fwelland/ResJect

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue on GF3, but the solution seems the same.

Remove the dependency from the lib directory and add it to the root of the ear. 
Then add the following to the application.xml

```
<module><ejb>Shared.jar</ejb></module>
```

Tip: using maven-ear-plugin you can automatically add dependencies as modules to your ear

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <displayName>...</displayName>
        <application-name>...</application-name>
        <defaultJavaBundleDir>lib</defaultJavaBundleDir>
        <!-- not generate application.xml! we include it ourselves -->
        <generateApplicationXml>false</generateApplicationXml>
        <modules>
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>...</groupId>
                <artifactId>Shared</artifactId>
                <bundleFileName>Shared.jar</bundleFileName>
            </ejbModule>
            </modules>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're using GlassFish 4, you're using Java EE 7, not Java EE 6.  In order for your situation to work, you need to register your shared jar as a module in the `application.xml`, so that it knows to scan it.

Comment: Well yeah (re: ee6 v ee7) -- I guess what i really meant I wish to stick with EE6 specs and features eventhough I may be running on an EE7 capable server.

Comment: At any rate I think I found on another SO post that suggests something similar but for a different problem.  You are referring to something like `<module><java>shared.jar</java></module>`  correct?     I thought the `<java>shared.jar</java>` was just for EE app clients?

Comment: Right, it would need to be defined as an EJB module instead of an app client module, this would be even though you're not defining any EJBs in it (really the use of ejb module is a misnomer at this point).  RE ee6 vs ee7, whenever you're on an eeX app server, you need to follow the rules of that ee spec, regardless of rules you may want to follow.

Comment: so <module><ejb>Share.jar</ejb><module> doesn't work in application.xml:  GF4 complains:  Exception while deploying the app [ResJect] : Invalid ejb jar Shared.jar: it contains zero ejb. A valid ejb jar requires at least one session/entity/message driven bean.

Comment: I was not expecting that result at all.  I'll need to look at the spec closer to see if that's a GF4 bug or not.  Try a java module, even though it's for application clients, it may still work for your use case.

Comment: The <module><java>Shared.jar</java><module> either.   GF4 was complaining about Expected to find an expanded directory for submodule Shared.jar but found a JAR.  That error seems to be related to NB's 'deploy from IDE' feature.    When I deploy as a proper ear -- I get ClassNotFound in the EJB jar -- as there is a interface file used in the EJB that is in 'Shared.jar'.   ......So I tried this:   put a copy of Shared.jar in the root to satisfy the <module> DD element and then ANOTHER copy in /lib  --- This is a bit smelly -- but it actually worked.  Maybe this is surprising maybe not .....

Comment: .....I can't decide.    It seems the @Producer/@Resource stuff got scanned & re-solved by the <java /> DD element and that put the producer in the CDI container for the EAR -- but that's it.  Other classes in that deploy unit were not available to other units in the EAR.   Putting a copy in /lib made the rest of the  classes available in ear classpath....    While technically I guees this is solved --  still trying to decide if I like the solution or if there is a better way.

Comment: Just to confirm, your `beans.xml` is a CDI 1.1/Java EE 7 compliant beans.xml (with bean-discovery-mode set to all)?

Comment: negative - you can see the source in the above github repo.   I'll note that in my real project; I did try the newer "beans_1_1.xsd" ns along with discovery all in my shared jar's, war's and EJB's beans.xml.   That didn't work with similar results.  I simplified the problem greatly with my sample; to extract this issue from the rest app.  I have a prod EE6/gf3.1.1 app and my objective is to get into gf4.0x with as few as possible changes...

Comment: ...so I got curious about the cdi 1.1 suggestion to try it out.  So Iput aside my InfiniSpan experiment and went ahead and tried implicit and explicit bean archives (with discovery all)...neither worked.  In the implicit case, I even added a 'dummy' RequestScoped bean -- nothing.      Further more I discovered my "success" from yesterday (the <java>Shared.jar</java> one) -- was a **not** a success after all -- I had forgotten to move the producer back into Shared.jar....So basically back to square 1...

Comment: I created the following bug, if you could add some more details around your use case in the comments that would help: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20867